# Simple proof linearly dependent column imply linearly dependent rows

Tags: linear-algebra, independence

I am wondering if there is an easy/simple way to show that if for a given a matrix $A$ there is a non-zero vector $x$ such that  $Ax=0$  then there is a non-zero vector $y$ such that $y^TA=0$
What I am after here is whether there is some way to go more or less directly from the fact that given that such an $x$ exists there is a $y^T$ that will  provide the linear combination of rows which results in a zero vector. In particular can we do it without already knowing that the span of the column space and row space are equal?

Comment: This isn't true for an infinite matrix: consider e.g.
$$
A=\pmatrix{0&1\\ &0&1\\ &&\ddots&\ddots\\ &&&\ddots}.
$$
Therefore, any proof of the statement must involve the fact that the size of the matrix (or the dimension of the ambient vector space) is finite.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want $A$ to be an $n \times n$ square matrix, otherwise the $1 \times 2$ matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$ is a counterexample.

(Side observation. The span of the columns need not be equal to the span of the rows - what you mean is that they have the same dimension.)

Assume there is is a non-zero $x$ such that $A x = 0$. We can assume WLOG that the first column of $A$ is a linear combination of the others, or more precisely
$$
x =
\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\
z
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $z$ is a column vector of length $n-1$.

If $B$ is the $n \times (n-1)$ matrix obtained removing the first column from $A$, then
$$\tag{prod}
A = B Z,
$$
where $Z$ is the $(n-1) \times n$ block matrix
$$
Z =
\begin{bmatrix}
z & | &I
\end{bmatrix},
$$
where $I$ is the identity $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ matrix.

Now (prod) shows the $n$ rows of $A$ are linear combinations of the rows of $Z$.  Since $Z$ has $n - 1$ rows, this means that the rows of $A$ are linearly dependent, that is, there is a $y \ne 0$ such that $y^{t} A = 0$.

I am aware of the fact that you might consider this argument not to be satisfactory, because it reproduces part of the proof that the row rank equals the column rank.

Comment: Thanks for the much needed clarifications and for pointing them out so tactfully. So I agree it should be narrowed to square matrices with a finite number of columns, yes it the  row and column dimensions, not the span that is equal. Now I will have to spend a little time to understand your argument.